# How to keep the order of the related messages in message process system?

Tags: message, middleware, distributed-computing, distributed

The system get messages from MQ. For the reason that the system has multiple VM, the real order of processing the messages may not be the same as the order in MQ.( etc. One later message may be processed, stored in the database before the previous message).

Now I want that the messages with same Business-ID can be processed as the order when it is sent.

I can get one proposal that we can use one VM and read messages from MQ. And get the Business-Id and distribute messages to target VM (messages with same Business-Id will be distributed to the same VM). It will solve this problem, but there is only one single thread to do the distribution job, the performance may not be good.

Is there any other ways to solve the problem? Any blog, paper, open source code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

One of the basic properties of messaging in distributed systems is that messages will be processed out of order. a common solution is to use a Saga (a state machine). With a Saga, you can identify the indexer or your business process (an orderId for example) and then manage the long-running process.

Here is an example of how NServiceBus is solving this issue: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/?version=core_7.2